# In Drupal 8 module creation, why don't I have to put the directories "modules" and "src" in the namespace of my yaml file?

Tags: 8

I watched a [tutorial](https://drupalize.me/videos/create-module-route-and-controller?p=2486) on Drupal module development, and the namespace he used didn't include modules or src in the yml file (it is around 4:30).  I'm sure this is a basic PHP question, but why didn't he have to put in those directories?

Comment: The summary [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2156625) explains it pretty nicely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Why", in a general sense, is for convenience. Drupal 8 uses [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloading and maps the respective module namespaces to each module's src/ directory. See [drupal_classloader_register](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_classloader_register/8.2.x)():

```
function drupal_classloader_register($name, $path) {
  $loader = \Drupal::service('class_loader');
  $loader->addPsr4('Drupal\\' . $name . '\\', \Drupal::root() . '/' . $path . '/src');
}
```